# Having hubot respond when a message does not match

Tags: javascript, hubot

I am programming a slack interface for [hubot](https://hubot.github.com/docs/) in javascript, and I want to have a default message when an invalid command is input. I currently have this in my code:

```
robot.respond(!(/command1/, /command2/, /command3/, etc.) function (msg) {
   msg.reply('Returned message')
})
```

While this does respond to all invalid messages, it also sends my response whenever I put in any valid command as well. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found there is an easier way to do what I want. Use the hubot support package at the following sire, which gives you a robot. reply all

https://www.npmjs.com/package/hubot-suggest

I then wrote the following code:

```
module.exports = function (robot) {
const text = dedent`
Command does not exist
Did you want one of the following commands?
'handel-codepipeline help'
'handel-codepipeline [deploy|delete]'
'canvas-update <sis_section_id> <curriculum_id> <title_code>'
'new repo' - creates a new githib repository
For more commands, type 'help'
`
robot.catchAll((msg) => {
    msg.reply(text)
})
```

}